# In Python, what's the difference between deepcopy and [each[:] for each in List]

Tags: python, list, copy, deep-copy

Below is the example code:

```
from copy import deepcopy
List = [range(3), range(3), range(3)]
a = deepcopy(List)
b = [each[:] for each in List]
```

I know the time required to initialize a is slower than b's time, but why does this happen? What's the difference between deepcopy and  [each[:] for each in List]? Why is deepcopy so slow?

Answer (score 6):

`each[:]` creates a *shallow* copy of each nested list. `copy.deepcopy()` would make a *deep* copy.

In this specific case, where your nested lists contain immutable integers, this difference doesn't actually matter; `deepcopy()` returns the integer unchanged when copying. But if there were *mutable* objects in the nested lists, then `deepcopy()` would continue to create copies of those, while your list comprehension would not.

For example, you'd see a difference when copying a list containing lists with with dictionaries:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> sample = [[{'foo': 'bar'}, {'ham': 'spam'}], [{'monty': 'python'}, {'eric': 'idle'}]]
>>> shallow = [each[:] for each in sample]
>>> deep = deepcopy(sample)
>>> sample[-1][-1]['john'] = 'cleese'
>>> sample
[[{'foo': 'bar'}, {'ham': 'spam'}], [{'monty': 'python'}, {'eric': 'idle', 'john': 'cleese'}]]
>>> shallow
[[{'foo': 'bar'}, {'ham': 'spam'}], [{'monty': 'python'}, {'eric': 'idle', 'john': 'cleese'}]]
>>> deep
[[{'foo': 'bar'}, {'ham': 'spam'}], [{'monty': 'python'}, {'eric': 'idle'}]]
```

Because the `deepcopy()` operation has to test each element in the nested lists, it is also slower; the list comprehension is the better option if you know that you don't need to produce a 'deeper' copy.

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn Pieters said each[:] will perform by creating a shallow copy of each nested list. If your list elements are immutable objects then you can use this, otherwise you have to use deepcopy from copy module.

It's possible to completely copy shallow list structures with the slice operator without having any of the side effects, have a look to the following snapshot:

```
LIST_1 = ['A','B',['AB','BA']]
print LIST_1
>>> ['A', 'B', ['AB', 'BA']]
LIST_2= LIST_1[:]
print id(LIST_1)
>>> 40427648
print id(LIST_2)
>>> 50932872  
LIST_2[2][1] = "D"
LIST_2[2][0] = "C";

print LIST_2
>>> ['A', 'B', ['C', 'D']] 
print LIST_1
>>> ['A', 'B', ['C', 'D']]
```

However in deepcopy method:

A solution to the described problems is to use the module "copy". This module provides the method "copy", which allows a complete copy of a arbitrary list, i.e. shallow and other lists. so you use `copy.deepcopy(...)` for deep copying a list:

```
deepcopy(x, memo=None, _nil=[])
```

The following script uses our example above and this method:

```
from copy import deepcopy

LIST_1 = ['A','B',['AB','BA']]

LIST_2= deepcopy(LIST_1)

LIST_2[2][1] = "D"
LIST_2[0] = "C";

print LIST_2
>>>['C', 'B', ['AB', 'D']]
print LIST_1
>>>['A', 'B', ['AB', 'BA']]
```

[image]

Therefore, a shallow copy of each nested list does not recursively makes copies of the inner objects. It only makes a copy of the outermost list, while still referencing the inner lists from the previous variable and that's why deepcopy is slower.